# ReadOnlyCollection or IEnumerable for exposing member collections?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, ienumerable, readonly-collection

Is there any reason to expose an internal collection as a ReadOnlyCollection rather than an IEnumerable if the calling code only iterates over the collection?

```
class Bar
{
    private ICollection<Foo> foos;
    
    // Which one is to be preferred?
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { ... }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Foo> Foos { ... }
}


// Calling code:

foreach (var f in bar.Foos)
    DoSomething(f);
```

As I see it IEnumerable is a subset of the interface of ReadOnlyCollection and it does not allow the user to modify the collection. So if the IEnumberable interface is enough then that is the one to use. Is that a proper way of reasoning about it or am I missing something?

Comment: If you're using .NET 4.5, you may want to try the new [read-only collection interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj133817.aspx). You'll still want to wrap the returned collection in a `ReadOnlyCollection` if you're paranoid, but now you're not tied to a specific implementation.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

**More modern solution**

Unless you need the internal collection to be mutable, you could use the [`System.Collections.Immutable`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/) package, change your field type to be an immutable collection, and then expose that directly - assuming `Foo` itself is immutable, of course.

**Updated answer to address the question more directly**

> Is there any reason to expose an internal collection as a ReadOnlyCollection rather than an IEnumerable if the calling code only iterates over the collection?

It depends on how much you trust the calling code. If you're in complete control over everything that will ever call this member and you *guarantee* that no code will ever use:

```
ICollection<Foo> evil = (ICollection<Foo>) bar.Foos;
evil.Add(...);
```

then sure, no harm will be done if you just return the collection directly. I generally try to be a bit more paranoid than that though.

Likewise, as you say: if you only *need* `IEnumerable<T>`, then why tie yourself to anything stronger?

**Original answer**

If you're using .NET 3.5, you can avoid making a copy *and* avoid the simple cast by using a simple call to Skip:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos {
    get { return foos.Skip(0); }
}
```

(There are plenty of other options for wrapping trivially - the nice thing about `Skip` over Select/Where is that there's no delegate to execute pointlessly for each iteration.)

If you're not using .NET 3.5 you can write a very simple wrapper to do the same thing:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Wrapper<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    foreach (T element in source)
    {
        yield return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that there is a performance penalty for this: AFAIK the Enumerable.Count method is optimized for Collections casted into IEnumerables, but not for a ranges produced by Skip(0)

Comment: If wrapping a List in a class, would it be better to do the above or have the wrapping class implement IEnumerable<T> and pass on GetEnumerator()?

Comment: @Andrew: It depends on the exact situation. Do you want your wrapping class act as the collection itself, or merely *contain* a collection?

Comment: @Jon, good question. I guess depending on which way one wanted to answer this either approach could be good. In my case, I think it is the collection itself so assuming passing on GetEnumerator() is a valid approach, then that is the way I would go. Thanks,

Comment: I'm slightly surprised that foos.Skip(0) does not compile to the same MSIL as foos.Select(x => x)... Does the use of an delegate always carry overhead?

Comment: @silasdavis: Why on earth would the compiler want to know about `Skip` vs `Select` calls? *Executing* a delegate will always carry an overhead, although it's likely to be minimal.

Comment: -1 Is it just me or is this an answer to a different question? It's useful to know this "solution", but the op has asked for a comparison between returning a ReadOnlyCollection and IEnumerable. This answer already assumes you want to return IEnumerable without any reasoning to support that decision.

Comment: The answer shows casting a `ReadOnlyCollection` to an `ICollection` and then running `Add` successfully. As far as I know, that should not be possible. The `evil.Add(...)` should throw an error. https://dotnetfiddle.net/GII2jW

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: Yes, exactly - that throws. But in my answer, I don't cast a `ReadOnlyCollection` - I cast an `IEnumerable<T>` which isn't actually read-only... it's *instead* of exposing a `ReadOnlyCollection`

Comment: Aha. Your paranoia would lead you to use a `ReadOnlyCollection` instead of an `IEnumerable`, in order to protect against the evil casting.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: Instead of exposing the underlying `List<T>` or whatever, yes.

Comment: @JonSkeet -  is it fine to use foos.AsEnumerable() instead of foos.Skip(0)  ?

Comment: @Ananth: No, because that's a no-op - the returned value could still be cast back to the collection type.

Comment: Given the popularity of this answer, I wonder if it might be worth it to add to it a couple of cents on `System.Collections.Immutable`?

Answer (score 50):

If you only need to iterate through the collection:

```
foreach (Foo f in bar.Foos)
```

then returning **IEnumerable** is enough.

If you need random access to items:

```
Foo f = bar.Foos[17];
```

then wrap it in **ReadOnlyCollection**.

Comment: @w0051977 It depends on your intent. Using `System.Collections.Immutable` as Jon Skeet recommends is perfectly valid when you're exposing something that is never going to change after you get a reference to it. On the other hand, if you're exposing a read-only view of a mutable collection, then this advice is still valid, although I would probably expose it as `IReadOnlyCollection` (which didn't exist when I wrote this).

Comment: `IReadOnlyList<T>` has the `[index]`er

Answer (score 35):

If you do this then there's nothing stopping your callers casting the IEnumerable back to ICollection and then modifying it. ReadOnlyCollection removes this possibility, although it's still possible to access the underlying writable collection via reflection. If the collection is small then a safe and easy way to get around this problem is to return a copy instead.

Comment: That's the kind of "paranoid design" I heartily disagree with. I think it's bad practice to choose inadequate semantics in order to enforce a policy.

Comment: You disagreeing doesn't make it wrong. If I'm designing a library for external distribution I'd much rather have a paranoid interface than deal with bugs raised by users who try to misuse the API. See the C# design guidelines at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2604h5s(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Yes, in the specific case of designing a library for external distribution, it makes sense to have a paranoid interface for whatever you're exposing. Even so, if the semantics of Foos property is sequential access, use ReadOnlyCollection and then return IEnumerable. No need to use wrong semantics ;)

Comment: You don't need to do either. You can return a read-only iterator without copying...

Comment: You don't need reflection to get back the underlying writable collection from a ReadOnlyCollection. Only (readCollection.GetEnumerator() as ICollection<Foo>).

Comment: @shojtsy Your line of code doesn't seem to work.  _as_ generates a _null_.  A cast throws an exception.

Comment: I believe the correct syntax is `readOnlyCollection.Items`
which returns an `IList<T>` that can be modified.

Comment: Why did you say "ReadOnlyCollection removes this possibility"? ReadOnlyCollection has implemented ICollection<T> explicitly, thus nothing stops you from assigning a ReadOnlyCollection instance to a ICollect<T> variable as well?

Comment: @joe Given that `ReadOnlyCollection`'s implementation of `ICollection<T>` will cause exceptions to be thrown whenever the latter's edit methods are called, the statement is indeed accurate.

Answer (score 3):

I avoid using ReadOnlyCollection as much as possible, it is actually considerably slower than just using a normal List.
See this example:

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
        //Use a ReadOnlyCollection around the List
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<int> mValue = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<int>(intList);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            intList.Add(i);
        }
        long result = 0;

        //Use normal foreach on the ReadOnlyCollection
        TimeSpan lStart = new TimeSpan(System.DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        foreach (int i in mValue)
            result += i;
        TimeSpan lEnd = new TimeSpan(System.DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        MessageBox.Show("Speed(ms): " + (lEnd.TotalMilliseconds - lStart.TotalMilliseconds).ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("Result: " + result.ToString());

        //use <list>.ForEach
        lStart = new TimeSpan(System.DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        result = 0;
        intList.ForEach(delegate(int i) { result += i; });
        lEnd = new TimeSpan(System.DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        MessageBox.Show("Speed(ms): " + (lEnd.TotalMilliseconds - lStart.TotalMilliseconds).ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("Result: " + result.ToString());
```

Comment: Premature optimization. By my measurements, iterating over a ReadOnlyCollection takes roughly 36% longer than a regular list, assuming you do *nothing* inside the for loop. Chances are, you'll never notice this difference, but if this is a hot-spot in your code and requires every last bit of performance you can squeeze out of it, why not use an Array instead? That would be faster still.

Comment: Your benchmark contains flaws, you are completely ignoring branch prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may want to use an interface, perhaps because you want to mock the collection during unit testing. Please see my [blog entry](http://nicksdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/01/interfacing-readonlycollection.html) for adding your own interface to ReadonlyCollection by using an adapter.