# How to prevent a method caller from modifying a returned collection?

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable, readonly-collection

I have methods returning private collections to the caller and I want to prevent the caller from modifying the returned collections.

```
private readonly Foo[] foos;

public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos()
{
    return this.foos;
}
```

At the moment the private collection is a fixed array, but in the future the collection might become a list if the need for adding new items at run time arises.

There are several solutions to prevent the caller from modifying the collection. Returning `IEnumerable<T>` is the simplest solution, but the caller can still up-cast the return value to `IList<T>` and modify the collection.

```
((IList<Foo>)GetFoos())[0] = otherFoo;
```

Cloning the collections has the obvious disadvantage that there are two collections that can evolve independently. So far I have considered the following options.

1. Wrapping the collection in `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.
2. Returning one of the LINQ iterators defined by the `Enumerable` class by performing a dummy projection like `list.Select(item => item)`. Actually I consider using `Where(item => true)` because the returned iterator seems more lightweight.
3. Writing a custom wrapper.

What I don't like about using `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is that it implements `IList<T>` and calling `Add()` or accessing the indexer will cause exceptions. While this is absolutly correct in theory, almost no real code checks `IList<T>.IsReadOnly` or `IList<T>.IsFixedSize`.

Using the LINQ iterators - I wrapped the code in an extension method `MakeReadOnly()` - prevents this scenario, but it has the taste of a hack.

Writing a custom wrapper? Reinventing the wheel?

Any thoughts, considerations, or other solutions?

---

While tagging this question, I discovered [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491375/readonlycollection-or-ienumerable-for-exposing-member-collections) I didn't notice before. Jon Skeet suggest to use the "LINQ hack", too, but even more efficient using `Skip(0)`.

Comment: Unless there are security issues (potentially hostile callers), I generally don't worry about protecting against unwise casting or calling Add on a ReadOnlyCollection. Foolish developers can use reflection and access internals, too. It's difficult to make code idiot-proof. The goal is to protect against innocent use of the public interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to achieve **exactly** what you are looking for in the current version of the framework.  It simply has no concept of an indexable immutable / read-only collection on both the concrete type and interface style.

As you pointed out, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` works OK on the concrete type side.  But there is no corresponding interface to implement which is also statically read-only.

You're only real choice is to ...

- Define your own collection class
- Either only implement `IEnumerable<T>` or define a need read-only interface which your collection implements.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it clearifies that there is no build-in support. A decided to stick with Enumerable.Skip(0).

Comment: @DanielBrückner: What real advantage does that have over wrapping in a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` and casting to `IEnumerable<T>`?  The fact that the resulting object can be cast to `IList<T>` will enormously improve the performance of some Linq methods like `Count` and `Last`.

Answer (score 0):

How about making a deep copy of the object being returned? [So there will be no effect on the original collection even if the caller decides to make changes to the copy returned]

Comment: A copy of the collection is not desirable, because the caller would just get a snapshot and wouldn't notice changes made to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

List and Array have a AsReadOnly method :

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos()
{
    return Array.AsReadOnly(this.foos);
    // or if it is a List<T>
    // return this.foos.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Comment: This methods return the collection wrapped in a ReadOnlyCollection<T> and I don't like that this class implements IList<T> as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases i create a methods insde the class to access individual elements of the private collection.
You also can realize indexer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) on the class that contains private collection.

Comment: Implementing a method to obtain a single element has at least two disadvantages - a second method or a property to return the number of elements in the collection is required and all the advantages of IEnumerable<T> - foreach and LINQ - are lost. Creating an indexer requires a method or property returning the number of elements, too, and some classes have several methods returning collections. This opts indexers out.

Comment: Yes, sure, it depends on your tasks.
But you can add a field that returns the number of elements in private collection.
You can also create inner class, that will realize access logic.