# When is a return type required for methods in Scala?

Tags: scala, methods, overloading, scala-2.8

The Scala compiler can often infer return types for methods, but there are some circumstances where it's required to specify the return type. Recursive methods, for example, require a return type to be specified.

I notice that sometimes I get the error message "overloaded method (methodname) requires return type", but it's not a general rule that return types must always be specified for overloaded methods (I have examples where I don't get this error).

When exactly is it required to specify a return type, for methods in general and specifically for overloaded methods?

Comment: As a matter of (my personal) style, I give explicit return types for all but the most simple methods (basically, one-liners with no conditional logic). Keep in mind that if you let the compiler infer a method's result type, it may well be more specific than you want. (E.g., `HashMap` instead of `Map`.)

Comment: @Randall yes, good point (about the return type being too specific).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Chapter 2. Type Less, Do More](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch02.html) of the **[Programming Scala](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/index.html)** book mentions:

> **When Explicit Type Annotations Are Required.**
>
> In practical terms, you have to provide explicit type annotations for the following situations:
>
> Method return values in the following cases:
>
> - When you explicitly call return in a method (even at the end).
> - When a method is recursive.
> - When a method is overloaded and one of the methods calls another. The calling method needs a return type annotation.
> - When the inferred return type would be more general than you intended, e.g., `Any`.

Example:

```
// code-examples/TypeLessDoMore/method-nested-return-script.scala
// ERROR: Won't compile until you put a String return type on upCase.

def upCase(s: String) = {
  if (s.length == 0)
    return s    // ERROR - forces return type of upCase to be declared.
  else
    s.toUpperCase()
}
```

> **Overloaded methods** can sometimes require an explicit return type. When one such method calls another, we have to add a return type to the one doing the calling, as in this example.

```
// code-examples/TypeLessDoMore/method-overloaded-return-script.scala
// Version 1 of "StringUtil" (with a compilation error).
// ERROR: Won't compile: needs a String return type on the second "joiner".

object StringUtil {
  def joiner(strings: List[String], separator: String): String =
    strings.mkString(separator)

  def joiner(strings: List[String]) = joiner(strings, " ")   // ERROR
}
import StringUtil._  // Import the joiner methods.

println( joiner(List("Programming", "Scala")) )
```

> The two `joiner` methods concatenate a `List` of strings together.
>   The first method also takes an argument for the separator string.
>   The second method calls the first with a “default” separator of a single space.
>
> If you run this script, you get the following error.

```
... 9: error: overloaded method joiner needs result type
def joiner(strings: List[String]) = joiner(strings, "")
```

> Since the second `joiner` method calls the first, it requires an explicit `String` return type. It should look like this:

```
def joiner(strings: List[String]): String = joiner(strings, " ")
```

---

Basically, **specifying the return type can be a good practice even though Scala can infer it**.

---

[Randall Schulz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200166/randall-schulz) comments:

> As a matter of (my personal) style, I give explicit return types for all but the most simple methods (basically, one-liners with no conditional logic).
>
> **Keep in mind that if you let the compiler infer a method's result type, it may well be more specific than you want. (E.g., HashMap instead of Map.)**

And since you may want to expose the minimal interface in your return type (see for instance this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596579/best-type-to-set-as-return-type-for-methods-that-return-a-collection)), this kind of inference might get in the way.

---

And about the last scenario ("When the inferred return type would be more general than you intended"), [Ken Bloom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197788/ken-bloom) adds:

> **specify the return type when you want the compiler to verify that code in the function returns the type you expected**

(The faulty code which triggers a "more general than expected return type was:

```
// code-examples/TypeLessDoMore/method-broad-inference-return-script.scala
// ERROR: Won't compile. Method actually returns List[Any], which is too "broad".

def makeList(strings: String*) = {
  if (strings.length == 0)
    List(0)  // #1
  else
    strings.toList
}

val list: List[String] = makeList()  // ERROR
```

, which I incorrectly interpreted and List[Any] because returning an empty List, but Ken called it out:

> `List(0)` doesn't create a list with 0 elements.
>   It creates a `List[Int]` containing one element (the value 0).
>   Thus a `List[Int]` on one conditional branch and a `List[String]` on the other conditional branch generalize to `List[Any]`.
>   In this case, **the typer isn't being overly-general -- it's a bug in the code**.
>   )

Comment: "When the inferred return type would be more general than you intended, e.g., Any." This is weird. Actually, I would consider that a bug in the Typer. I have never experienced something like that. Do you have an example?

Comment: @soc: http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch02.html does have one example where returning a `List(0)` (`List` of size 0) will return and `List[Any]` instead of `List[String]` unless you specify the return type.

Comment: `List(0)` doesn't create a list with 0 elements. It creates a `List[Int]` containing one element (the value `0`). Thus a `List[Int]` on one conditional branch and a `List[String]` on the other conditional branch generalize to `List[Any]`. In this case, the typer isn't being overly-general -- it's a bug in the code. Which adds another rule for specifying return types: **specify the return type when you want the compiler to verify that code in the function returns the type you expected.**

Comment: @Ken: good catch. I have included your comment (and others) in my answer.