# Scala type inference on overloaded method

Tags: scala, type-inference

Given this code:

```
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) {
  require(d != 0)
  private val g = gcd(n.abs, d.abs)
  val numerator = n / g
  val denominator = d / g

  def this(n: Int) = this(n, 1)

  override def toString = numerator + "/" + denominator

  def +(r: Rational) = new Rational(numerator * r.denominator + r.numerator * denominator, denominator * r.denominator)

  def *(r: Rational) = new Rational(numerator * r.numerator, denominator * r.denominator)

  def +(i: Int) = new Rational(i) + this

  private def gcd(a: Int, b: Int) : Int = {
    if (b == 0) a else gcd(b, a % b)
  }

}
```

why isn't scala able to infer that +(i: Int) returns a Rational number? (fsc gives `overloaded method + needs result type` error)

if i change that method to:

```
def +(i: Int): Rational = { new Rational(i) + this }
```

It works...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found a thread in the scala mailing list with exactly the same question [here](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Error-overloaded-method-needs-result-type-td1954896.html). The answers there explains a bit why is it required to give the return type. After investigating a bit more I also found this: [When is a return type required for methods in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127208/when-is-a-return-type-required-for-methods-in-scala/3127260#3127260). If I should quote the answer from there:

> **When Explicit Type Annotations Are Required.**
>
> In practical terms, you have to provide explicit type annotations for the following situations:
>
> Method return values in the following cases:
>
> - When you explicitly call return in a method (even at the end).
> - When a method is recursive.
> - ***When a method is overloaded and one of the methods calls another. The calling method needs a return type annotation.***
> - When the inferred return type would be more general than you intended, e.g., `Any`.

Answer (score 3):

In this case it could infer the right type, but it just isn't clever enough. It's easy to construct some pathological examples with overloaded methods where things get really messy, so I guess that's why the Scala team decided to make a clear cut and require the return type. This is similar to recursive methods, where you need the result type, too, even though the compiler could infer it in many cases.