# Why is return type needed on overloaded scala function?

Tags: scala

```
  def toJson[T](obj: T) = {
      gson.toJson(obj)
  }

  def toJson[T](list: Seq[T]) = {
      toJson(seqAsJavaList(list))
  }
```

This doesn't compile. And that's documented as a feature ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845569/scala-type-inference-on-overloaded-method)):

> When a method is overloaded and one of the methods calls another. The calling method needs a return type annotation.

The question is: why?

From the above link + some additional thought from colleagues, here are the possible reasons:

- scala uses return type as well to determine overloaded methods. Is this the case, and why is it neded? (Java doesn't use return types, for example)
- partial functions - if one of the methods doesn't have arguments and the other one does, toJson() may be viewed as a partial function, so it's not certain whether the return type is String or Function

I know it's a best practice to specify the return type anyone, but why actually is the above snippet not compiling, and if return type inference isn't good enough, why is it there in the first place?

Comment: Did you mean for the second one to call `gson` also?  As it's written, it's infinitely recursive.

Comment: @barnesjd : if `seqAsJavaList` is any indication, it's not - `java.util.List` is not a `Seq[T]`.

Comment: Oh, right... in that case it calls the other function, which is his question.  Thanks

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato with an implicit conversion in scope, the call could be recursive; the conversion is applied when you know the expected type, after overloading resolution, i.e., you can't tell a priori (before inference) which method is intended. This is purgatory for the sin of overloading.

Comment: @som-snytt : I know, hence my answer (full disclosure, just in case: only the *last* sentence was added *after* your comment was posted :) ).

Comment: First bullet: to pick overload, it only looks at "applicable" functions, where applicable means args conforms and also result type conforms if there is an expected type, like `val x: String = f(y)`. Second bullet: "partially applied" function; yes, good one.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the main reason, but note that another reason for an explicit parameter is given as:

> When a method is recursive.

**The problem is, depending on the return type of the "calling" function, the call can either be to its namesake, or to itself (i.e. *recursive*).**

Let's say:

```
trait C

class A extends C

def a(obj: A) = {2}
```

Now consider:

```
def a[T <: C](obj: T): Int = {
 a(obj)
}

a(new A) //an Int, 2
```

versus:

```
def a[T <: C](obj: T): Any = {
 a(obj)
}

a(new A) //infinite recursion
```

Since inferring the return type of a recursive function is finite-time undecidable *in general*, inferring the return type of the "calling" function is also finite-time undecidable *in general*.