# Scala Overloaded Method Needs Return Type

Tags: scala

Why is Scala telling me I  need to add a return type to the overloaded method?

```
case object MyObject {

    def apply(a: String) = apply(a, "")

    def apply(a: String, b: String) = a concat b
}
```

Compilation Error:

`overloaded method apply needs result type`

Comment: I don't think the type inferencer would like it.

Comment: @m-z Interestingly enough I am not getting any warnings at write-time about this.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, but it's preferable to include return types on all public methods anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The discussion [here](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Error-overloaded-method-needs-result-type-td1954896.html) describes that Scala (1) might use the return type to find the correct function and (2) would have problems with implicit parameters. Seems that they decided to make return types mandatory [on some functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845569/scala-type-inference-on-overloaded-method) to catch all these potential cases.