# What is the difference between using the return statement and defaulting to return the last value?

Tags: scala, methods, return

I am learning Scala and I noticed something about using the return statement.

So, obviously in Scala, if you don't have a return statement, the last value is returned by default. Which is great. But if you use the return statement without specifying the return type, Scala says `"error: method testMethod has return statement; needs result type"`

So this works

```
  def testMethod(arg: Int) = {
    arg*2
  }
```

but this gives the error

```
  def testMethod(arg: Int) = {
    return arg*2
  }
```

This makes me scratch my chin and go

> Mmmmmmmm... There must be a reason for that.

Why is the explicit type declaration needed when you use a return statement but not when you let Scala return the last value? I assumed they were exactly the same thing, and that return statements are just for if you want to return a value inside a nested function/conditional, etc. (In other words, that a "return" statement is automatically inserted to your last value by the compiler.. if not present anywhere else in the method)

But clearly I was wrong. Surely there must be some other difference in the implementation?

Am I missing something?

Comment: I imagined it doesn't compile because you're actually use the keyword `return` and I was right. I'll post my answer in a second. Basically, if you use return, it's going to look for that you declared its returned type instead of inferring the return type on its own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have multiple exit points from your method, it may be impossible for the compiler to infer the return type. The only way you can get multiple exit points from your method, is by using multiple `return`s. (Or one `return` plus the implicit return.)

Since the rules, when it works and when it doesn't, are pretty complex, it may look to the user that it sometimes randomly works and sometimes doesn't. Simply forbidding type inference altogether in the presence of an explicit `return` is a much simpler rule, even if a bit restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

This question was ["When is a return type required for methods in Scala?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127208/2567273) A different question entirely, but it's in the same realm as OP.

---

This answer explains when (not why) you have to give it a return type:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127260/2567273

The [Chapter 2. Type Less, Do More](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch02.html) of the **[Programming Scala](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/index.html)** book mentions:

> **When Explicit Type Annotations Are Required.**
>
> In practical terms, you have to provide explicit type annotations for the following situations:
>
> Method return values in the following cases:
>
> - When you explicitly call return in a method (even at the end).
> - When a method is recursive.
> - When a method is overloaded and one of the methods calls another. The calling method needs a return type annotation.
> - When the inferred return type would be more general than you intended, e.g., `Any`.

---

This doesn't explain why you have to specify a return (only when), but I'll stick to what I said in my comment. The reason you have to specify a return type when you use the `return` keyword is because the compiler is going to look for that you gave it a return type or else it will infer the return type on its own as if you didn't use `return` at all. If you specifically use `return` you're helping the compiler out by telling it what to return and then it expects you to tell it what type you are returning.

Comment: I'm not sure that justification makes any sense.

Comment: From a compiler's POV I think it does. Sometimes the situation is too complex for it to infer what the return type is. When it can't, you need to tell it. Even in basic situations like OP's example, using `return` creates a contract initiating that you will also tell the return type. I'm only throwing this answer out given what I know from my compilers class. I'm not a scala programmer.

Comment: It would be a trivial compiler step to prune an unnecessary final `return` from the AST. So I think it would be more accurate to say (as the other answer does) that they chose consistency of rules with early `return`--the only necessary use of `return`--over providing inference for an unnecessary final `return`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think should the type-inference mark the return the type as for:

```
def func(n:Int) = {
    if(n<10) return 23;
    if(n>10) true else false;
}
```

The first line suggests the return value should be of type `Int`. But the implicit return suggests a boolean. So it becomes quite debatable on what exactly should be the return type. `Int`,`Boolean` or `Any`?

Had explicit return not been used, it is quite simple to determine the return type of function. But with it, its a bit vague and unknown. The simplest solution would be for the user to explicitly specify the return type. This makes life much easier for the compiler.

Moreover the team wished to discourage usage of explicit return types, so making people put manual types goes with the intention :)