# overload method needs result type in Scala?

Tags: scala

Here is my code and I actually do not need any return values and types, and wondering how to handle this error?

Error of "overload method needs result type" is on this line `foo (start, end, 14)`

```
object HelloWorld {

  def foo(start: String, end: String) = {
     foo (start, end, 14)
  }

  def foo(start: String, end: String, id: Int) = {
     println("Hello, world!")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    foo("hello", "scala")
  }
}
```

Corrected version of code,

```
object HelloWorld {

  def foo(start: String, end: String): Unit = {
     foo (start, end, 14)
  }

  def foo(start: String, end: String, id: Int): Unit = {
     println("Hello, world!")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    foo("hello", "scala")
  }
}
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Per my understanding you'll need explicit return values for overloaded functions in Scala always. In this case the return values would be `Unit`

Comment: @kaskelotti, vote up. I have posted corrected version of code, tested it works and if you could double confirm my fix is correct, it will be great. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is a return type required for methods in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127208/when-is-a-return-type-required-for-methods-in-scala)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Here is my code and I actually do not need any return values and types, and wondering how to handle this error?

You do. Scala doesn't allow you to have two `foo` methods without specifying return types (both `Unit` in this case).

Comment: Thanks Alexey, vote up. I have posted corrected version of code, tested it works and if you could double confirm my fix is correct, it will be great. :)

Comment: Is there some documentation as two why Scala needs you to tell it the return type?