# Variable Setter Type Error: Overloaded method needs result type

Tags: scala

I have the following piece of code in Scala.

```
object ABC {
  var x = 100
  def x_=(x:Int) = this.x = x
  
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    var y = ABC
    println(y.x)
  }
}
```

The third line `def x_=(x:Int) = this.x = x` raises the following error: `Overloaded method needs result type`. I don't have any other methods with the name `x_`.  I already did some research and not able to find the reason. One of such links in Stack Overflow is: [When is a return type required for methods in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127208/when-is-a-return-type-required-for-methods-in-scala)

Comment: Your question is confusing. First you talk about a syntax error. Then you cite an error message that sounds like *not* a syntax error but a type error. Except if there were a syntax error, than you *cannot possibly* get a type error, because in order to get a type error, the compiler would have to parse the code. And it also seems like the error message you cited does not actually exist, I cannot find *a single reference* to that message in the entire compiler source code, and this very question is the only reference to that error in the entirety of Google's index.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Come on, he's obviously not aware of the difference between syntax and type errors, so teach him rather than blaming him for getting it wrong and confusing you. Also, quick google search with the before-edit error message "scala overloaded method result type" gives you plenty of relevant results.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, just wondering...type error is not detected by compiler and we have a different mechanism to run over the program to find that ?

Comment: No, he means that a syntax error is different than a type error. Before the compiler tries to type check your code, it will first need to understand it from a syntax point of view. This means making sure the statement in your code are understood. The next step is to typecheck it, which is when a type error would be detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define `var x`, a setter `def x_=(x: Int)` is generated for you, so you don't have to define it explicitly.

When you write

```
def x_=(x: Int) = this.x = x
```

Scala translates `this.x = x` to `this.x_=(x)` which means you're defining `x_=` as a recursive method. This is wrong is this case, but the error message is not super helpful, until you set a return type. This is because Scala wants recursive methods to have explicit return types, since there is sometimes no way to infer the return type otherwise.

In summary, you're actually defining this:

```
def x_=(x: Int) = x_=(x)
```

Now, if you put an explicit `Unit` return type, you will get the following very clear error message saying you can't define `x_=` because it already exists.

```
  var x: Int = 42
  def x_=(x: Int): Unit = this.x = x

ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method x_= in object X of type (x: Int)Unit
and  variable x in object X of type (x$1: Int)Unit
match argument types (Int)

method x_= is defined twice;
  the conflicting variable x was defined at line 5:7
```

If you absolutely need to define `x_=` because you need to do some extra processing before setting `x`, you can just use another name for the `x` variable and make it private to your class:

```
class X(private var _x: Int) {
  def x_=(x: Int): Unit = {
    // Do some extra work here, then set _x
    _x = x
  }
  def x: Int = _x // Also need to provide a getter explicitly in this case
}
```

Comment: Thanks @francoisr for the detailed explanation. I was not aware that the creating a var, automatically creates a setter too!

Comment: @user3103957 well that is the point of a public variable so it can be modified from the outside. Also, that is usually thought in any basic course or tutorial to the language, if you are not following any you should. Finally, it seems you have a tendency to make everything mutable, you may want to stick to the opposite and do everything immutable by default.