# Make method that uses SQLiteConnection more reusable

Tags: c#, sqlite, generics

I am using `sqlite-net` in my project and have a helper class called SqLiteHelper. Inside this class I have a simple method that returns `TableQuery` results as a List.
**Example:**

```
public static class SqLiteHelper
{
    public static List<Contact> GetTableQueryResults()
    {
        List<Contact> contacts;
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabasePath))
        {
            connection.CreateTable<Contact>();
            contacts = connection.Table<Contact>().ToList();
        }

        return contacts;
    }
}
```

I want to make this method reusable to use it in the future in other context. For example when I will have another project with a different class then 'Contact'.  I tried it myself by refactoring it to this:

```
public static IList<T> GetTableQueryResults<T>()
{
    List<T> contacts;
    using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabasePath))
    {
        connection.CreateTable<T>();
        contacts = connection.Table<T>().ToList();
    }

    return contacts;
}
```

But the SQLiteConnection.Table<> method throws the following error:
[image]

Any ideas how I can make this method reusable?
I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596579/best-type-to-set-as-return-type-for-methods-that-return-a-collection) but it's not in connection with `SQLite`.

Comment: DB Connections are not supposed to be reused.  Create, use and dispose of them in the smallest scope possible.  The DB Provider implements *connection pooling* to make things more efficient.  There is plenty of documentation in it.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp the db connection isn't reused here.. it's created in a using block and will be disposed.  I suspect the OP meant reusable in terms of a method that you can pass the generic type to.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Yes thats what I want to achieve. It looks like below my question got answered using `new constraint`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide the generic type constraint of `T` as `where T : new()` in your method.  The `new()` constraint lets the compiler know that any type argument supplied must have an accessible parameterless constructor.

Method:

```
public static IList<T> GetTableQueryResults<T>() where T : new()
{
    List<T> contacts;
    using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabasePath))
    {
        connection.CreateTable<T>();
        contacts = connection.Table<T>().ToList();
    }

    return contacts;
}
```

Read about `new` constraint at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it looks like the **constraint** topic is what i missed. When I want to use the method now is this approach okay: `contactsList = (List<Contact>) SqLiteHelper.GetTableQueryResults<Contact>();`

Comment: it would be flagged as an unnecessary cast @Stan1k.. you don't need to cast to `List<Contact>`, by virtue of specifying `Contact` in the method, it will return a `List<Contact>` type.  On a side note, the method is doing more then one operation, a Command and Query (or CreateTable then `.Table<T>().ToList()`)... is the approach okay?... probably not

Comment: @BrettCaswell Alright, I removed the cast. Splitting up the method was my next approach, thanks for the reminder.