# Return IEnumerable<IMyInterface> from List<MyInterfaceClass>

Tags: c#, interface

**EDIT**: This question would be invalid in .NET 4 since it actually works as desired.

I have a Data class that must implement an interface like this:

```
public interface IData
{
   IEnumberable<IOther> OtherList { get; }
   IOther AddOther();
   void RemoveOtherData(IOther data);
}
```

But I am stuck with declaring the actual member in Data

```
public class Data : IData
{
   // desired, always return the same reference
   public IEnumberable<IOther> OtherList { get { return _mOtherList } }
   // Non persistent reference not desirable.
   public IEnumerable<IOther> OtherList { get { return _mOtherList.Select(x => x as IOther); } }        
   List<IOther> _mOtherList = new List<Other>(); // error, type mismatch
   List<Other> _mOtherList = new List<Other>(); // error, property return type mismatch
   IEnumerable<IOther> _mOtherList = new List<Other>(); // ok, but cannot use List methods without casting.
}
```

What would be the best solution in this case?

Comment: The first member in your interface has no name and thus can't compile.

Comment: wow.. you are quick. i am still editing..

Comment: Why can't you just say `_mOtherList = new List<IOther>()`?

Comment: cos then need type casting when working privately inside Data on Other. I hope to look for some semantics to avoid that.

Comment: Why would you need typecasting? You can directly add anything that implements `IOther` to a `List<IOther>`

Comment: @Jake What version of the .NET Framework are you targeting?

Comment: @jamietre if I want to retrieve something back from the List<IOther> I need to cast it back to Other to work on it at the same tier as Data.

Comment: @Jake In that case one of your code samples actually works and the question is incorrect. `List<Other> _mOtherList = new List<Other>();` is the line that would work for you coupled with `public IEnumberable<IOther> OtherList { get { return _mOtherList; } }` assuming `Other` implements `IOther`.

Comment: @Jake Or was this a question about which to pick for best practise? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jake - since you are programming with interfaces in the first place why would you need to work with `Other` except to instantiate it? Use `IOther` types internally too.

Comment: @jamietre It could be that the strong type is defined in the same layer so it may make sense to need to use it.

Comment: Maybe a question of style, then, that's akin to using `internal` access which I try to avoid as much as possible. e.g. I try to have every public method/property of an object match its interface, so I wouldn't (generally) have a reason to be passing around class types. If it comes up then I would cast it explcititly.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I realized that the answerers are basically saying that "covariance" (don't know what that is, yet) exists in .NET 4. But my Visual Studio is telling me it is an error, type mismatch.

Comment: @Jake I'm going to guess then that you aren't actually targeting .NET 4? Open the project properties and go to the "Application" tab and make sure "Target framework" is 4 or 4 client profile - this assumes VS 2010. As well as changing the target framework, it uses the relevant C# compiler too. Co- and contravariance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I really hope that that is NOT all there is to target .NET 4 because it is really not working...

Comment: @Jake It now depends on what piece of code you are referring to. I have commented on one of the answers to this effect for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Data : IData
{
   public IEnumerable<IOther> OtherList { get; private set; }        
   List<Other> _mOtherList = new List<Other>();

   public Data()
   {
     OtherList=mOtherList.Cast<IOther>();
   }
}
```

On .net 4 `IEnumerable<out T>` is co-variant. i.e. a class that implements `IEnumerable<Other>` automatically implements `IEnumerable<IOther>` too. So could also simply write:

```
public class Data : IData
{
   public IEnumerable<IOther> OtherList { get{return mOtherList;} }        
   List<Other> _mOtherList = new List<Other>();
}
```

But I'd avoid that, since it breaks encapsulation and allows outsiders to modify your list.

```
((List<Other>)MyData.OtherList).Add(...);
```

Comment: +1 Must admit, after that slog this is the only answer covering all bases.

Answer (score 1):

Other class must implement IOther interface and you don't need to cast.

When you declare _mOtherList, it's IEnumerable, so you can't use list methods. Declare it as a list.

```
public class Data : IData
{
   List<IOther> _mOtherList = new List<Other>();

   public IEnumberable<IOther> OtherList { get { return _mOtherList } }

   IOther AddOther()
   {
       return null;
   }
   void RemoveOtherData(IOther data){}
}
```

Your Other class:

```
class Other : IOther
{
   //some members
}
```

Comment: You leak a reference to your private collection to consuming code.

Comment: If that's an issue, you can look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/491591/205859)

Comment: @CodeInChaos may i ask what is the "leak a reference" here?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları My Visual Studio says `List<IOther> _mOtherList = new List<Other>(); ` is a compile error, type mismatch.

Comment: @Jake Have you implemented IOther in Other class like above?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları To really isolate the issue, I created a new project/solution, check that project > properties > Application > target framework is .NET Framework 4 and wrote your code. But it still gives the error. What am I missing?

Comment: @Jake `List<IOther> list = new List<Other>();` won't work in .NET 4. We are referring to `List<Other> list = new List<Other>();` works with `IEnumerable<IOther> publiclist = list;`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth AHHH that's right. Comment credits given. Thanks!

Comment: @Jake lol np, glad it's sorted for you. In another comment I linked co and contravariance, worth a read. I'll admit I don't hit it explicitly very often so my head compiler can never guarantee whether its in play or not lol

Answer (score 0):

As IEnumerable is covariant this is fine:

```
    public interface IInterface{}

    public class ClassA : IInterface{}

    public class ClassB
    {
        private readonly List<ClassA> _classAs;

        public IEnumerable<IInterface> Data{ get { return _classAs; } }
    }
```