# Guidelines for returning Generic Interface Collections

Tags: generics, collections, interface, dictionary, return-type

I typically try to follow a methodology of having arguments to methods be as generic as possible and return types as generic as necessary and have run into a problem to which the answer is not overly clear to me.

I have a control which operates on a structure like:

```
IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<MyObject>>>
```

So that supplying two keys, we get a collection of objects back.  Pretty straight forward.

I have a class

```
ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

which is just that, a readonly dictionary so that any IDictionary methods which would alter the dictionary throw an NotSupportedException();

The dictionary on which the control operates comes out of a MyObjectRepository which returns a

```
ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ReadOnlyCollection<MyObject>>>
```

So the question is, should I update the return type on my repository to return

```
IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<MyObject>>>
```

or ...?  I don't think it would be correct to update the method to take a readonly dictionary as that is unnecessarily limiting.

It seems that this makes it less clear about the return type.  Also, the interface defines the ReadOnlyDictionary as the return type so that implementing classes cannot return dictionaries which would allow modification.  It just feels like if the interface is returning a collection which should be read only, then the return type should reflect that.  By specifying the generic IDictionary<...> return type, methods which use the interface may try to modify the dictionary only to run into a NotSupportedException.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this are appreciated!

**UPDATE**
As it turns out, the real issue here is with the ReadOnlyCollection.  It simply should be replaced by IEnumerable and it simplifies much of the work converting between various return types.

See [ReadOnlyCollection or IEnumerable for exposing member collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491375/readonlycollection-or-ienumerable-for-exposing-member-collections) and notice Jon Skeet's answer.  This is why I love SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My inclination would be to define interfaces: `DoubleKeyLookup<out ValT>`, and derived from that, `DoubleKeyLookup<in KeyT1, in KeyT2, out ValT>`.  The first would have methods like `GetSequence(Object key1, Object key2);`, `TryGetSequence`, and `GetSequenceOrEmpty` (the former would throw on not-found; the second would return `null`; the third would return `Enumerable<ValT>.Empty`).  The second would be similar, but with 'key' parameters of the specified types.  Most consumers would probably use the second, but the first would be usable in case one wanted to e.g. see if a particular `Animal` was in a dictionary where all the keys were `Cat`.

Comment: I like the flexibility of this answer and it seems to follow linq where we have a method which will throw, one which returns null, and one which returns an empty.  Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most user-friendly way I can think of is:

Since ReadOnlyDictionary implements IDictionary<,> but throws exceptions on unsupported operations, I would recommend that the simplest and most readable way be to return a ReadOnlyDictionary<,> that implements IReadOnlyDictionary<,> instead. IReadOnlyDictionary<,> would simply derive from IDictionary<,> since they're functionally equivalent.

The name "IReadonlyDictionary" in the method prototype would then indicate to the caller that methods that alter the dictionary may not work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like both answers provided and would probably use this for more simple projects.