# What happens with properties and arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, properties

Okay, I've this classes and main. I'm on VS 2010 Ultimate and .NET 4 Client.

```
internal class tezt
{
    private int[] _numeros = new int[5];
    public int[] Numeros
    {
        get { return _numeros; }
    }
}
public class tezt2
{
    private int[] _numeros = new int[5];
    public int[] Numeros
    {
        get { return _numeros; }
    }
}
class tezt3
{
    private int[] _numeros = new int[5];
    public int[] Numeros
    {
        get { return _numeros; }
    }
}
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var arrNums = new tezt();
        var arrNums2 = new tezt2();
        var arrNums3 = new tezt3();
        Console.WriteLine(arrNums.Numeros[0]);
        arrNums.Numeros[0] = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(arrNums.Numeros[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(arrNums2.Numeros[0]);
        arrNums2.Numeros[0] = 6;
        Console.WriteLine(arrNums2.Numeros[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(arrNums3.Numeros[0]);
        arrNums3.Numeros[0] = 7;
        Console.WriteLine(arrNums3.Numeros[0]);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

What's happening with these lines:

```
arrNums.Numeros[0] = 5;
arrNums2.Numeros[0] = 6;
arrNums3.Numeros[0] = 7;
```

Isn't supposed that because the classes from which those objects are derived from haven't a `set` parameter, those asignations must not be allowed?

What can be done to avoid that, to restrict that, thad doing thiks like `arrNums.Numeros[0] = 5;` throws a error?

Comment: You're not setting the property. You are *getting* the array from the property and assigning to its elements. If you do not want this, do not expose an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the `Numeros` property, you are modifying an element at an index inside that property. You are only using the *getter* for that property.

The assignment that isn't allowed is assigning a new value to that object's property:

```
arrNums.Numeros = new int[5]; // will not compile.
```

You could make the getter return an `IEnumerable<int>` to protect it:

```
class tezt3
{
    private int[] _numeros = new int[5];
    public IEnumerable<int> Numeros
    {
        get { return _numeros; }
    }
}
```

You could also use a `ReadOnlyCollection`. The pros and cons of using `IEnumerable<T>` vs `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` are discussed in depth in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/491375/497356).

Comment: Fast question, if I'm using your code, and I also want to assing elements to _numeros via a set parameter, how can I accomplish it?

Comment: You could provide a setter that sets the underlying collection as well: `set { _numeros = value.ToArray(); }`

Comment: Aja, now, when I assign someting, I say `arrNums.Numeros = new[] {5};`, and if I'd a `arrNums.Numeros = new[] {5, 6, 7, 8, 9};` before, the elements 6, 7, 8 and 9 will be lost. Anyway to avoid this?

Comment: Write an `Add`  method to add items to the collection

Comment: ...seems like it's eaiser to make a method (forget properties) that only has a return and zero assignments...

Comment: That would be a property with just a `get` like in the answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10452/discussion-between-mishamosher-and-andrew-whitaker)

Answer (score 0):

Can I also advice not using arrays on properties. Here is a quote from [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)

> Properties that return arrays can be very misleading. Usually it is
>   necessary to return a copy of an internal array so that the user
>   cannot change the internal state. This could lead to inefficient code.
>
> In the following example, the Employees property is accessed twice in
>   every iteration of the loop. That would be 2n + 1 copies for the
>   following short code sample:

```
Company microsoft = GetCompanyData("MSFT");
for (int i = 0; i < microsoft.Employees.Length; i++)
{   
  if (microsoft.Employees[i].Alias == "kcwalina")
  {  ...  }
}
```

[Brad Abrams](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/), a annotator of the book, remarks on this pitfall:

> Some of the guidelines in this book were debated and agreed on in the
>   abstract; others were learned in the school of hard knocks. The
>   guideline on properties that return arrays is in the school of hard
>   knocks camp. When we were investigating some performance issues in
>   version 1.0 of the .NET Framework, we noticed that thousands of arrays
>   were being created and quickly trashed. It turns out that many places
>   in the Framework itself ran into this pattern. Needless to say, we
>   fixed those instances and the guidelines. - Brad Abrams