# JSON is not deserlizing using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net

Hello here is my response.

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "ServiceId": 222977,
      "ServiceName": "Mayur  Lohite"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my class

```
public class ServiceContainer
{
    List<Services> services { get; set; }
}
public class Services
{
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string? ServiceName { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to convert like this

```
ServiceContainer? services = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceContainer>(response.ToString());
```

But not getting the data in **services** list.

Comment: try changing `List<Services> services { get; set; }`  to `public  List<Services> services { get; set; }`

Comment: Personally, I'd use `public IEnumerable<Services> Services { get; init; }`, as you (probably) don't want to modify the collection after it's been initialised.  Also `class Services` is a bad name for a single item, the class name should be singular and the collection name should be plural.

Comment: @Neil I would argue that `IReadOnlyCollection` will do better in this case.

Comment: @GuruStron  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491375/readonlycollection-or-ienumerable-for-exposing-member-collections/491591#491591
Unless the consumers of your methods are idiots and try casting back to the concrete type.

Comment: @Neil `IEnumerable` will not save in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the JSON that you are showing, the below would be the appropriate class,

```
public class ServiceContainer
{
    public Service[] services { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `List<Services>` would've been fine for the type of the `services` property. You didn't need to change the type. The key difference is that the `public` keyword was missing in the original code. Private properties aren't processed.

Comment: I have done a very silly mistake. Thank you @Anand for pointing it out.