# What is a read only collection?

Tags: c#, wcf, readonly, readonly-collection

I ran a security code analyst i found myself having a [CA2105 warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182299.aspx). I looked at the grade tampering example. I didn't realize you can assign int[] to a readonly int. I thought readonly was like the C++ const and makes it illegal.

The How to Fix Violations suggest i clone the object (which i don't want to do) or 'Replace the array with a strongly typed collection that cannot be changed'. I clicked the link and see 'ArrayList' and adding each element one by one and it doesn't look like you can prevent something adding more.

So when i have this piece of code what is the easiest or best way to make it a read only collection?

```
public static readonly string[] example = { "a", "b", "sfsdg", "sdgfhf", "erfdgf", "last one"};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return collection as read-only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55502/return-collection-as-read-only)

Comment: A readOnlyCollection = Normal collection - Add/remove APIs - Set Indexer

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The easiest way to have a collection which you cannot modify is to use

[ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx?queryresult=true)

Example from MSDN:

```
List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();
dinosaurs.Add("Tyrannosaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");
dinosaurs.Add("Compsognathus");

ReadOnlyCollection<string> readOnlyDinosaurs = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(dinosaurs);
```

Answer (score 13):

```
public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> example
    = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(new string[] { "your", "options", "here" });
```

(although it should still probably be exposed as a `get` property rather than a public field)

Comment: I would second here on using the `readonly` keyword for the variable as well. Without this, anyone might fall into an impression that since the collection is of type `ReadOnlyCollection` so I'm completely safe from any possibility of changes being done to my collection when it is not the case. One might not realize that the collection is read-only but the variable pointing to it is not. What a `ReadOnlyCollection` would mean if I can reassign the variable itself to a new collection altogether. +1.

Comment: @RBT note that readonly is a lie; readonly fields can absolutely be mutated. You have to cheat a little, of course...

Comment: It took me a while to digest [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722571/c-sharp-and-immutability-and-readonly-fields-a-lie). Thank you for showing me the light.

Answer (score 12):

If you're working with arrays, you can use

```
return Array.AsReadOnly(example);
```

to wrap your array in a read-only collection.

Answer (score 3):

```
var readOnly = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(example);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> readOnlyCollection = 
            new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(example);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a similar solution, but I wanted to still be able to modify the collection from inside the class so I chose the option outlined here: 
http://www.csharp-examples.net/readonly-collection/

In short, his example is:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<int> _items = new List<int>();

    public IList<int> Items
    {
        get { return _items.AsReadOnly(); }
    }
}
```