# What does immutable and readonly mean in C#?

Tags: c#, immutability, readonly

Is it correct that it is not possible to change the value of an immutable object?

I have two scenarios regarding `readonly` that I want to understand:

1. What if I have a collection and mark it as `readonly`, like the following. Can I still call `_items.Add`?

   ```
   private readonly ICollection<MyItem> _items;
   ```
2. And also for the following variable, if later on I call `_metadata.Change` which will change the internal values of a couple member variable in the `Metadata` instance. Is `_metadata` still immutable?

   ```
   private readonly Metadata _metadata;
   ```

For both variables above, I totally understand that I can't directly assign new values to them outside of initializer and constructors.

Comment: I was sure this would have been asked here before, but I can't find a duplicate. There is one for Java, but none I can find for C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# and immutability and readonly fields... a lie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722571/c-sharp-and-immutability-and-readonly-fields-a-lie)

Answer (score 25):

I suggest you to read the series of blog posts by Eric Lippert. The first part is [Immutability in C# Part One: Kinds of Immutability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx). Very informative and helpful, as always. The series describes what does it mean for a variable to be *readonly*, *immutable* etc. in details.

Generally, `readonly` means only that you can't re-assign a field outside the constructor. The field itself can be modified as long as it stays the same instance. So yes, you can add elements to the collection stored in `readonly` field.

About mutability, this is more complex and it depends a bit what kind of mutability you consider. When `Metadata` internal values are references and those references itself (the instances it point to) doesn't change, you could say `Metadata` stays not mutated. But it is mutated *logically*. See Eric's posts for more insights.

Comment: Nice link: I only hope that the gist of 'your answer' isn't contained within the link, especially if for some reason that link were no longer available. You need to include the gist of your answer from that link as part of your well-worded answer that is deserving of the +5 votes.

Comment: @IAbstract: Right, I've updated my answer to make it more complete. Anyway, there's nothing more than in other answers, so I'll upvote them, too.

Answer (score 8):

An *immutable* object is one that cannot be changed, once created. In C# strings are immutable. If you look at the string manipulation routines you can see that all of them *return a new, modified, string* and leaves the original string unchanged.

This facilitates the string handling considerably. When you have a reference to a string, you can be sure that noone else will unexpectedly change it under your feet.

`readonly` is something else. It means that the *reference* cannot be changed, once set and that it can only be set during object construction. In your examples you can change the contents of `_items` or the properties of `_metadata`, but you cannot assign another `ICollection<MyItem>` to the `_items` member or another `Metadata` instance to `_metadata`.

`readonly` is set on the *reference* to an object. Immutability is a property of the object itself. These can be freely combined. To make sure that a property is not changed in any way, it should be a readonly reference to an immutable object.

Answer (score 7):

Marking a field as read-only only means that you cannot change the value of that field. It has no bearing on the internal state of the object there. In your examples, while you would not be able to assign a new metadata object to the _metadata field, nor a new ICollection to the _items field (outside of a constructor that is), you can change the internal values of the existing objects stored in those fields.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing preventing you from mutating an object stored in a `readonly` field. So you CAN call `_items.Add()` and `metadata._Change()` outside the constructor/initializer. `readonly` only prevents you from **assigning** new values to those fields after construction.

Answer (score 3):

`private readonly ICollection<MyItem> _items;`

Does not prevent items from being added. This simply prevents `_items` from being re-assigned. The same is true for `_metadata`. Accessible members of `_metadata` can be changed - `_metadata` cannot be re-assigned.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes.
2. Readonly doesn't equal to immutable. You can still call _metadata.Change.

Answer (score 2):

The readonly keyword applies to a variable - this means you can't assign another value to it, but you can alter its internal state. That's why you can alter a collection's items but you can't assign a new collection to the variable.

Comment: This is confusing. `readonly` applies to a member *variable* -- nothing to do with references at all. Consider: `readonly int x = 2;`.

Answer (score 0):

In languages like C++ there are quite a few different uses of the keyword "const", it is partly easy for developers to pass constant parameters and also constant pointers of constant values.

That is not easy in C#.
We need to build immutable class by definition, which means Once an instance is created, there is no way it can be changed programmatically.

Java has a little easier way than C# because of the keyword final and its usages.

Lets consider this example and see how immutable it is..

```
public sealed class ImmutableFoo
    {
        private ImmutableFoo()
        {

        }

        public string SomeValue { get; private set; }
        //more properties go here

        public sealed class Builder
        {
            private readonly ImmutableFoo _instanceFoo = new ImmutableFoo();
            public Builder SetSomeValue(string someValue)
            {
                _instanceFoo.SomeValue = someValue;
                return this;
            }

            /// Set more properties go here
            /// 

            public ImmutableFoo Build()
            {
                return _instanceFoo;
            }
        }
    }
```

**You can use it like this**

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ImmutableFoo foo = new ImmutableFoo.Builder()
                .SetSomeValue("Assil is my name")
                .Build();

            Console.WriteLine(foo.SomeValue);
            Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to terminate");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```