# When creating an immutable type in .net is it valid to have public fields?

Tags: c#, .net, immutability

So when designing an immutable class should it use get properties as such

```
public sealed class Person
{
    readonly string name;
    readonly int age;

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
    }
}
```

Or is it valid to expose public readonly fields

```
public sealed class Person
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly int Age;

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does immutable and readonly mean in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849114/what-does-immutable-and-readonly-mean-in-c)

Comment: @ssg: Rather not a duplicate; that other question doesn't even mention properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While both options will leave you with objects whose fields cannot be changed from the outside, the same guidelines apply for immutable objects as otherwise:

Using properties instead of publicly exposing your fields is still an advantage; you are not checking any input values, but still, future versions of your type might compute some of the values rather than read them directly from an internal field. By using properties, you hide that implementation detail and hence increase your flexibility for future changes.

Answer (score 1):

One major problem with `public readonly` class fields in .net is that the from the perspective of outside code, the only thing the `readonly` declaration does is mark the field with a readonly attribute (I forget the spelling and casing).  Although some languages will honor such attributes in outside code, a language can ignore such attributes if it so chooses.  If an object with `public readonly` fields is exposed to code written in a language that ignores the readonly attribute, that code could write to such fields just as easily as if the attribute didn't exist.

Structures are a different matter.  If a struct stored in field `foo` has a field of its own named `boz`, then code which can write to `foo` can write to `foo.boz`, and code which cannot write to `foo` cannot write to `foo.boz`, *regardless of whether `boz` is public or private, or whether it is intended to be mutable or immutable*.  This is because if `foo1` is a struct of the same type, the statement `foo = foo1` does not make `foo` refer to the same instance as `foo1`, but rather works by *mutating all of the public and private fields in `foo` to match the values of corresponding fields in `foo1`*.

Boxed value types are even worse; if one has an `Object` which holds a boxed instance of any value type, the value may be replaced with another of that type.  Even supposedly-immutable types like `Int32`, when boxed, behave as mutable reference types.

Consequently, when using structure types, one should enforce immutability by storing the structures in private fields of the precise structure type.  Attempting to make struct fields immutable can make instances of the type more of a nuisance to work with, but will have no real effect on the mutability or immutability of struct instances.

Comment: are you sure " a language can ignore such attributes if it so chooses"?

Comment: @Simon: The CLI sure doesn't care - try to change the value of a `readonly` attribute via reflection, and (e.g. as opposed to assigning something to a property for which there is no setter defined) there will be no exception; the attribute will just be changed.

Comment: That adds an interesting angle on the conventional way of declaring dependency properties, BTW.