# Can C# cast const?

Tags: c#, c++, casting

If an object is readonly or const, is it possible to cast that object to make it writable?
Something similar to C++ const_cast.

Comment: Are you talking about the object itself, or the reference to the object?

Comment: If you need to write to it, why not just drop the whole const idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not possible in C#, just like it's not possible in C++. In C++, if the object is really const, you cannot `const_cast` the constness away and write to it without invoking undefined behaviour:

```
struct foo { const int x; };

foo a;
int& b = const_cast<int&>(a.x);
b = 17; // invokes undefined behaviour
```

A `readonly` field in C# only means that the field itself cannot be reassigned. It's akin to `T *const` or `T&` in C++. You can change the referenced object at will through its members.

```
class Foo { public int x; }
class Bar { public readonly Foo y = new Foo(); }

Bar a = new Bar();
a.y.x = 3; // valid
a.y = new Foo(); // invalid
```

Well, I'm not telling the whole truth. You can cheat and change `readonly` fields through reflection<sup>1</sup>:

```
typeof(string).GetField("Empty").SetValue(null, "bar");
// this effectively makes string.Empty equal to "bar", with disastrous consequences
// It requires full trust though.
// Obviously, it's evil.
```

If it is a `const` field however, not even this trick will work.

`const` fields are *hardcoded* in assemblies that use them, instead of keeping references to the original assembly:

```
// Assembly A.dll
public class Foo { public static const int X = 42; }

// Assembly B.dll
int y = Foo.X;
// this is the equivalent to:
int y = 42;
```

This means that if you recompile A.dll and change the value of `Foo.X` to 23, B.dll will still use 42 until it is recompiled.

All that said, if you want to have a field that you want to change, just don't make it `readonly`. If you want it to be mutable by the class, but immutable from the outside, make it private and add a read-only property (note: this is not the same as a `readonly` field):

```
class Foo
{
    private int bar;
    public int Bar
    {
        get { return bar; }
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This [is not really guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/#comment-743456), but it works on the Microsoft implementations. If you're wondering why this hack works at all, you can read [Eric Lippert's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722571/6722620#6722620). Be sure to also read the answer about [`readonly` on value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063212/6063546#6063546). And it goes without saying, **don't do this at home**.</sub>

Comment: "unlike in C++" not true. It's just that C# references behave more like pointers and `readonly` is more like `Bar*const` rather than `const Bar*`.

Comment: Actually in C++ casting away constness does not invoke undefined behaviour. Modifying a const object, for example through a non-const reference or pointer created by casting away constness, is what invokes undefined behaviour. But as long as you don't change the const object, there is no UB. So in your example the casting away is completely fine, albeit unnecessary (cou can assign const int to int any day). If you tried const_cast<int>(a.x)=5; - that would be UB.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. I hope I fixed all the not so correct details :)

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to amend the value of the `const` itself.  All you can do is take a copy and change that copy.  Unless I'm misunderstanding the question...?

Bear in mind that in C# `const` is quite a limited keyword anyway, you can only declare certain things as `const` and only at compile time:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b(v=VS.100).aspx

Not sure why you'd want to mutate a constant.

Answer (score 1):

No. The reference or value will be read only.

You can however modify the properties of references or you could just make a copy of a value.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are not readonly or const, only variables are. That means you can assign a value to such a variable only once (in the case of `const`) or only until the owner object is constructed (in the case of `readonly`).

The object assigned to a `readonly` variable can still be changed, though, unless it's immutable (like `string`).

Answer (score 0):

You can cast in CSharp `readonly` away (which is equilant to C++ `const`). CSharp `const` could be translated to C++ with `constexpr` which can't be casted away.

To do so you can call `Unsafe.AsRef` - which has the same meaning as C++ `const_cast`:

```
using System;

class App{
   static readonly int i = 42;
   static void Main(){
       Console.WriteLine(i);
       System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.AsRef(i) = 777;
       Console.WriteLine(i);
   }
}
```

The same would look in C++ like:

```
#include <iostream>

class App{
public:
    static inline int iStorage= 42;
    static inline const int& i = iStorage;

    static void Main(){
       std::cout << i << '\n';
       *const_cast<int*>(&i) = 777;
       std::cout << i <<'\n';
   }
};

int main(){
    App::Main();
}
```

Just in case of `static const` C++ implementations are allowed to store the data in readonly-memory (which is explicitly allowed by the standard).
This is done usually for simple types like `int` - the reason is that there was no constexpr but the same behaviour was wished - therefore `static const` has sometimes the same meaning as `constexpr`.