# Enumerable: is "materialize" an official term?

Tags: linq, extension-methods, enumerable, deferred-execution

Is "materialize" a good name for a code like this, or is there a better (and official) one?

```
enumerable as ICollection<T> ?? enumerable .ToArray()
```

EDIT: I clarified the code (and its purposes)

```
// or "MaterializeIfNecessary"
public static IEnumerable<T> Materialize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    // if you use code analysis tools like resharper, you may have to return a 
    // different type to turn off warnings - even a placeholder interface like 
    // IMaterializedEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T> { } 

    if (source == null) return null;

    return source as ICollection<T> ?? source.ToArray();
}
```

The problem:

```
static void Save(IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    // The following code is Resharper suggested solution to 
    // "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable" warning
    // ( http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Possible+multiple+enumeration+of+IEnumerable ):
    strings = strings as string[] ?? strings.ToArray(); // you're not calling 
                                                        // ToArray because you 
                                                        // need an array, here

    if (strings.Any(s => s.Length >= 255)) throw new ArgumentException();

    File.AppendAllLines("my.path.txt", strings);
}
```

With the extension method, the first line should become more declarative:

```
strings = strings.MaterializeIfNecessary();
```

Comment: I'd call it `AsReadOnly` or `ToReadOnlyCollection`

Comment: @Magnus that should be an answer :) BTW I think `AsReadOnlyCollection` describes result better

Comment: Why would you cast IEnumerable to IReadOnlyCollection? http://stackoverflow.com/a/55661/211627

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I'll do that.

Comment: It's only purpose is:
1) call deferred execution immediately
2) and/or prevent multiple enumerations
(in those points/algorithms you need it)

The return type should be also "IEnumerable<T>", I use IReadOnlyCollection only to let code analysis tools (like resharper) understand that the method returns a "static" copy of source (as ToArray()/ToList() do).

Try/casts are to prevent useless "materialization" of already "materialized" sources.

I was in a hurry, I'll edit the post with more clear info as soon as I can

Comment: @Magnus: I agree that the name should have the "IfNecessary" subfix (or something like that). I used to name it "PreventMultipleEnumerations", but its purpose could also be to "flush" the deferred execution, so I decided to rename it, searching for an official term. Because of its purpose, if source is already "materialized", is useless (and unefficient) to ToList()/ToArray() it againg

Comment: I've edited the question, I'm sorry if it wasn't clear from the beginning. I was looking for the name of this:
enumerable as ICollection<T> ?? enumerable .ToArray()

Comment: @Notoriousxl I think you should rather change your save method ta take in `IList<string>` instead.

Comment: I dont think the answerers got what you were trying to ask. What you're trying to do is exactly "materializing" the `IEnumerable<T>` as a solid collection type since it can also be merely a query. And you have done it quite good (I mean the method implementation). But there is a catch here: your method returns either the existing collection (by a mere cast) or a new collection. For the first operation a verb like `Materialize` is good as a function name since you're acting on the list, but for the second operation, something like `To...` is more consistent with framework defined functions.

Comment: But that doesn't go well with its first operation. Anyway adding "IfNecessary" is not required, in fact I would suggest against it. May be a better naming is `AsCollection` or even just `Materialize` is not bad. Another suggestion is to return `ICollection<T>` since you're executing the call and mostly something more fleshed out than an `IEnumerable<T>` makes sense there. See a related link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621561/is-there-a-way-to-memorize-or-materialize-an-ienumerable

Comment: @nawfal that's exactly what I did, since I found that the term is used in official MSDN articles too. :) But I didn't return ICollection<T>, since it exposes "write" methods.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it `ToReadOnlyCollection`. It gives more information about what the function is actually doing. 
As for materializing the source it seems to do so only if `ToArray()` is called. (Wrapping the source only would not materialize it)

Comment: IEnumerable is already read only, so I still think `AsReadOnlyCollection` is a little better name :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yes, that name would also work. Especially if the function only wrapped the  source `IEnumerable`. But it seems it sometimes calls `ToArray` before the wrapping that's why `To` might be a better naming.

Comment: `ToXY` is best, because as a extension method it can be used like `ToList()` or `ToArray()`. But I do not understand why one needs that.

Comment: Yep, I already looked on framework methods like `AsEnumerable` and also think that `AsXXX` not good here)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819990/enumerable-is-materialize-an-official-term/14820288#comment20761949_14819990

Answer (score 1):

As @Magnus already suggested, `ToReadOnlyCollection` is a good descriptive name for your method. Also I think `AsReadOnlyCollection` is not that good name. Usually `AsXXX` methods do not covert or wrap source. Such methods simply return source as one of interfaces already implemented by source. You can use such method instead of casting.

And `Materialize` tells totally nothing about intent of method. What does it mean? I will be able to touch my sequence with hands? It will be printed on paper? Saved to file?

And yes, I also don't understand why you need to convert `IEnumerable` which is already read only to `ReadOnlyCollection`.

Comment: The underlying collection that the source `IEnumerable` points to might not be readonly, you may be able to cast it to a normal list and add stuff to it. If the collection _is_ a readonly collection that is not possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819990/enumerable-is-materialize-an-official-term/14820288#comment20761949_14819990